# How to create TestNG run configuration for multiple projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

The service I'm working on consists of multiple projects in my Eclipse workspace. They are all modules of a single Maven project if that matters.

I'm working on a functionality that spans across more than one Eclipse project. I'm marking my TestNG tests with the annotation to define a group of tests. I'd like to be able to run all the tests related to the functionality with a single run configuration in Eclipse to easily check for regression.

Unfortunately TestNG run configuration requires choosing a single project. Is there a way around this?

## Example

Let's say I have this test in project `appliances`:

```
@Test(groups = {"coffee"})
public class CoffeeMachineTest {
  //...
}
```

.. and in project `tableware` some other test:

```
@Test(groups = {"coffee"})
public class CoffeeCupTest {
  //...
}
```

I've grouped both tests in a TestNG group `coffee`, because they test different pieces of a functionality of making and serving coffee.

Eclipse projects `tableware` and `appliances` are both modules of a parent Maven project `Bar`.
I want to make sure everything is ready for serving coffee in my bar, so I'd like to create an Eclipse run configuration that would allow me to run all tests from group `coffee`. Unfortunately I'm stuck, because I need to choose a single project here:

[image: mockup of Eclipse add TestNG run configuration]

Is there some other way to group TestNG tests from multiple Eclipse projects and have them called from a single run configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out. In my case one project was referenced in the build path of the other. TestNG run configurations set for the master project also executed tests from the referenced project (they are on the class path, after all).

**To refer to the example above, let's say project `tableware` is on build path of project `appliances` (you need a cup to use coffee machine, don't you?). In that case I should create a TestNG run configuration in project `appliances`, select the test group `coffee` and voila, coffee tests from both projects can be executed.**

If you have two projects that don't depend on each other, a workaround may be to create another dummy Java Project which has no own sources, just the two other projects added to the build path. Then you create the test configuration on the dummy project.
I guess in some cases there might be classpath conflicts, though.